# Return data from MySQL table with PHP/PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PHP and very new to PDO. Everyone's been telling me to learn.

I've manage to establish a connection to my database, and I'm trying to return my results and wrap each row in a `DIV`, but it's only returning an array with all the column titles.

I currently have:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$q   = $conn->query($sql) or die("failed!");
while($r = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    print_r($r);
}
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction or give me some useful sites that can help?

Comment: Thats in a seperate file that i link to with an include, the above works as it pulls my data, but in an ugly array

Comment: tip: fetchAll() already retrieves all of the rows in the result set. there's no point in calling it in a while loop, because it'll have fetch all the rows on the first iteration anyways.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");

$stmt->execute();

foreach( $stmt as $row )
{
    echo "<div>" . $row['column'] . "</div>"
}
```

Comment: what's the point in preparing a statement with no parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

It was easier for me to do this...

```
while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)){

    echo '<div>';
    echo $r['id'];
    echo $r['first_name'];
    echo $r['surname'];
    echo $r['hometown'];
    echo $r['facebook'];
    echo '</div>';

}
```

Comment: i recomand you to read about yii cms , and you will see why i told you to use the fields array; yii uses automated generated classes for each of the db tables, and each class controlls a table; just use the fields array and make it easyer in the future; imagine if you have to write 100 functions and in each function you write again and again all the $variable = $row['key']; what if you have 40 fields ? inserting, searching, updating, deleting ... to much code ...

Comment: That has nothing to do with yii - he could just loop over the fields here like he was trying to do initially... he just gave up :-)